Shopify Admin API: I want to get the total number of items sold of a product with a product_id
I am using the Shopify GraphQL admin API to get the details of each of the products. But I am not able to get an important detail for the product - that is the total number of orders for this particular product or in other words - the total number of items sold of this product using a product_id or something equivalent.
Is there any way to get this number of products sold without traversing all of the orders on the store and checking for the matching product_ids of the product.
Any kind of help would be extremely helpful. Thank you.

I think you need to check this GQ documentation to search order by SKULink
